# Flask webapp : 'Token' object has no attribute 'test' | render_template error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, flask, deployment

Code in **Fake_News_Det.py** :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import PassiveAggressiveClassifier
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

app = Flask(__name__)
tfvect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_df=0.7)
loaded_model = pickle.load(open('D:\Fake_News_Detection\model.pkl', 'rb'))
dataframe = pd.read_csv('D:\Fake_News_Detection\data.csv')
x = dataframe['text']
y = dataframe['label']
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

def fake_news_det(news):
    tfid_x_train = tfvect.fit_transform(x_train)
    tfid_x_test = tfvect.transform(x_test)
    input_data = [news]
    vectorized_input_data = tfvect.transform(input_data)
    prediction = loaded_model.predict(vectorized_input_data)
    return prediction

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form['message']
        pred = fake_news_det(message)
        print(pred)
        return render_template('index.html', prediction=pred)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html', prediction="Something went wrong")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

After running the code, and viewing it on local port it shows an error :-

> AttributeError AttributeError: 'Token' object has no attribute 'test'

It have list of errors in sequence of type jinja errors, but what I think is

```
File "D:\Fake_News_Detection\Fake_News_Det.py", line 31, in home
return render_template('index.html')
```

This has something to do with, although I have index.html file in templates folder

**My file path :**
Pl go through these image files https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbGZt.jpg

EDIT:
**index.html** code :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fake News Detection System</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

</head>

<body>
 <div class="login">
    <h1>Fake News  Detector</h1>

    <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="POST">
        <textarea  name="message" rows="6" cols="50" required="required" style="font-size: 18pt"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Predict</button>

            <div class="results">

    {% if prediction == ['FAKE']%}
    <h2 style="color:red;">Looking Spam⚠️News </h2>
    {% elif prediction == ['REAL']%}
                <h2 style="color:green;"><b>Looking Real News</b></h2>
    {% endif %}

    </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

**style.css** code :

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
.btn { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; padding: 4px 10px 4px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #333333; text-align: center;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); vertical-align: middle; background-color: #f5f5f5; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#e6e6e6, GradientType=0); border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6; border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); cursor: pointer; *margin-left: .3em; }
.btn:hover, .btn:active, .btn.active, .btn.disabled, .btn[disabled] { background-color: #e6e6e6; }
.btn-large { padding: 9px 14px; font-size: 15px; line-height: normal; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
.btn:hover { color: #333333; text-decoration: none; background-color: #e6e6e6; background-position: 0 -15px; -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; transition: background-position 0.1s linear; }
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover { text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); color: #ffffff; }
.btn-primary.active { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }
.btn-primary { background-color: #4a77d4; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#6eb6de), to(#4a77d4)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#6eb6de, endColorstr=#4a77d4, GradientType=0);  border: 1px solid #3762bc; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled] { filter: none; background-color: #4a77d4; }
.btn-block { width: 100%; display:block; }

* { -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -ms-box-sizing:border-box; -o-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box; }

html { width: 100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }

body {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #092756;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:1.2px;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%),-moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%, rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), linear-gradient(135deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3E1D6D', endColorstr='#092756',GradientType=1 );

}
.login {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

.login h1 { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); letter-spacing:1px; text-align:center; }

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
}
input:focus { box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); }
```

Comment: pls paste the code/content of index.html.

Comment: @simpleApp Check now, I have updated

Comment: commented some lines to run on my setup i.e from `loaded_model = pickle.load(open('D:\Fake_News_Detection\model.pkl', 'rb'))` to `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)`. and when `http://127.0.0.1:5000` , it opened the web page. This looked all okay, so could not recreate. T

Comment: Shall I provide you the github code? @simpleApp

Comment: @simpleApp reply brother

Comment: hi there, this works well for me, so could not reproduce; so don't think that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there try to change the python version. sometimes downgrading and upgrading helps.

It will best work on 2.7.8+

Comment: Worked bro installed 2.7.0 and was working with 2.9.x

Comment: Good to know that helped